# How can I change the timezone of the date I'm inserting into my database?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

When I insert a timestamp into my database the value is about 10 hours back from my local time. The database is hosted on Godaddy's server.

I have changed my php5.ini file and added `date.timezone = 'Europe/Istanbul'`

(it was america/phoenix as default) when I checked with `phpinfo();`

Then I ran this code:

```
if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
    echo 'date_default_timezone: '. date_default_timezone_get() .'<br />';
}

if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone');
    echo date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time()); 
}
```

It's OK also same as my local time

But when i insert data it's get America/Phoenix timestamp which is -10 hours from my local time

Here is my insert code

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO cepbank (username, trans_id, bank, tutar, operator) VALUES ('$username', '$trans_id', '$bank', '$tutar', '$operator')");
```

and here is my MySql Table

```
CREATE TABLE `cepbank` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(11) collate utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `trans_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bank` varchar(11) collate utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `tutar` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `operator` varchar(32) collate utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `tarih` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci COMMENT='CepBank Gelen' AUTO_INCREMENT=143 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you use `default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for tarih field. And it uses the unadjusted server date. Get the adjusted timestamp in php:

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time ());
```

then add it into the query:

```
INSERT INTO cepbank 
    (tarih, username, trans_id, bank, tutar, operator)
VALUES 
    ('$timestamp','$username', '$trans_id', '$bank', '$tutar', '$operator'
```

Comment: @PcRestorer Can you print $timestamp before executing the INSERT and exit the script? What's it's value?

Comment: 1368809605 like this something

Comment: @PcRestorer Sorry, you need to convert timestamp to MySQL format before inserting it. Try the new code.